# Blue line around image

Tags: 2010, error

I am using with SPD 2010, I am working with minimal master page to try to make it look less "SharePoint".

I added an image to the body and I mapped a hotspot.  After I saved and published a blue line came up around the image I inserted. Is there a way to get rid of the blue line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SharePoint.

Add a css class to your image tag, then add the following style

```
<img class="no-border" src="...">

<style>
.no-border, .no-border a {
   border: none;
}

</style>
```

Comment: lml MdMazzotti THANKS MUCH! I APPRECIATE YOUR HELP IT WORKED PERFECTLY